# Same exception in second try catch "insert statement conflicted with the foreign key constraint"

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
[Route("API/Add")]

[HttpPost]
public GenericClasss AddData(CAddData_Request Data)
{
        GenericClasss Obj = new GenericClasss();

        try
        {
            Obj = _Base.AddDataa(Data);                   
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            string JsonData = _Base.ConvertJsontoString(Data);
            _Base.ServiceLogException(ex, ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName, JsonData);
        }

        return Obj;
    }    
}

public void ServiceLogException(System.Exception ex, string MethodName, string Data)
{
    try
    {
        AppException _Exception = new AppException();
        _Exception.Employee_ID = null;
        _Exception.Method = MethodName;
        _Exception.Page = "";
        _Exception.Line = ex == null ? "0" : Convert.ToString(new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(ex, true).GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber());
        _Exception.Object = Data;
        _Exception.Message = ex == null ? null : ex.Message;
        _Exception.CreatedDate = System.DateTime.UtcNow;
        _Exception.ExceptionType = 2;
        _Exception.IsSolved = false;

        DB.AppExceptions.Add(_Exception);
        DB.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception exa)
    {
    }
}
```

**Problem:**

If the `AddData` method generates an exception

> Insert statement conflicted with the foreign key constraint

then it will go to the catch block and insert the exception entry into the database.

But my `ServiceLogException` method also generates the same exception

> Insert statement conflicted with the foreign key constraint

Comment: Since insert is violating foreign key constraint please ensure values you are assigning to your entity model does not have incorrect values per the database constraints. Example, _Exception.ExceptionType = 2; but in your database foreign key to ExptionType cannot hold value 2

Comment: do you use the same db context when saving exception to db?

Comment: @Raxit but if anonymous user change value of model then what will do?

Comment: @LeszekRepie yes, private Web_Entities DB Declare at top of the class

Comment: @ManishVadher Make sure model state is valid under all circumstances before you push it to the database

Comment: @Raxit Yes it is right but how we check "Insert statement conflicted with the foreign key constraint" Exception in model state?

Comment: @ManishVadher You can't, all I am saying is your model needs to be valid so that you can push details to the database but that will not prevent the error you are facing. You need to ensure the values assigned to model does not violate database constraints that you have setup. To nail down further which foreign key constraint is violated just construct the insert statement manually into your database with the values you receive from your model. That will take you close to the error.

Comment: @Raxit then what is the solution for above problem?

Comment: @ManishVadher did you try my suggestion? put your findings what you tried.